# Equivalence Principle on Earth

Tags: reference-frames, acceleration, equivalence-principle, coriolis-effect

I've read that, according to the Equivalence Principle, no experiment can distinguish between uniform acceleration and gravity.  If one is in the classically-described elevator with a basin full of water on the Earth, Coriolis forces will cause the draining water to circulate around the drain.  No such phenomenon will occur in the uniformly accelerating elevator.

How does the Equivalence Principle account for this circumstance?

Comment: The Coriolis force is caused by Earth's spin, not just its gravity.

Comment: Also, it's a common misconception that Coriolis force make any significant impact on vortexes in drains.

Comment: user1079505 is correct , you can reference at; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_force#Draining_in_bathtubs_and_toilets

Comment: Where did you read that "no experiment can distinguish between uniform acceleration and gravity?" The equivalence principle says that *local* experiments cannot tell the difference.

Comment: The 4 comments do not address the question nor do they reflect on it.  As such, they are without merit.  Here's why.  The question is a thought experiment.  Whether the Coriolis force is tiny is not relevant.  The experiments discussed in the Wkpdia article can, in principle, be conducted in the elevator (but thanks, I no longer subscribe to that particular myth).  The first comment insults us and the PSE.  As to where I read xxx, Is this a proper comment? Sabine Hossenfelder's YTube video stated it word-for-word, but I first saw it in Max Born's "Einsteins Theory of Relativity" [Dover 1965].